# MySql connection reuse for different requests

Tags: java, mysql, connection

Is it possible to create one MySql connection while i am logging in , and in can be used by  different user for the same login purpose?

Comment: Read up on [Connection Pooling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connection-pooling.html) or [connector/j](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-j2ee-concepts-connection-pooling.html)

Comment: xQbert thanks! is it possible to achieve this connection reuse using single server/host , to avoid too many connections problem!!!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. Max Pool Size and Min Pool Size can be set to say ensure a min of 3 connections always stay open and a max of 10 are allowed.  This means the system will allow up to 10 connections to occur and after a 3 minute period of inactivity (by default) on a connection the pool size would drop back down but never fall below 3. This has the benefit of reducing overhead on the application server and database and scaling up in times of high traffic.  "A connection pool of 15-20 connections can serve a relatively moderate load (600 **concurrent users**) "

Comment: i mean , suppose i have a single server , and i want to configure it in such a way, that it can handle 10000 concurrent users. if it is possible with a single server or do i have to use cloud services to scale up my configurations.

Comment: From the connector/j article: "if you take Oracle's Java Petstore blueprint application for example, a connection pool of 15-20 connections can serve a relatively moderate load (600 concurrent users)"  If you expand that to 100000 concurrent users... Then you're in the pool of range 250 -333 connections...assuming "Moderate" load.  Each connection has overhead, additional processes on the server eat into RAM.  So while I'm pretty sure you CAN do this; I'm not sure you would want to on one server as I think you'd start to hit a swap file.  Question may be better suited to serverfault.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://compendiuminstitute.net/download/shared-mysql.pdf
The above link will help you set up a shared MySQL database server for multiple users.

Comment: Hi rvp_15 ! thanks a lot for this tutorial. Actually  i am looking for a solution which is something like this : there is a quiz application , one user logs in and now i want to use same the mysql connection for  anthother 10 logins of different quiz application users.